# How to install Cangjie (Traditional Chinese) input for Ubuntu Mate 16.04 PowerPc

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, mate

I am a newbie to Linux (and Ubuntu).

Installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04 PowerPC on PowerMac G5 dual 2.3GHz, with English (US) as the selected language and keyboard.

Then installed (?) Cangjie 3 with  "sudo apt-get install fcitx-table-cangjie3".

The Cangjie3 icon "倉" does show up on the uppper right panel under the Fcitx icon. Selected it and tried to type on LibreOffice Write only showed the English characters, not the expected Chinese word.

Opened Facitx Configuration under Control Centre, Cangjie3 Chinese (Taiwan) was listed under Input Method. Click the keyboard icon at the lower right corner, it showed English (US) as the Default keyboard layout. Clicked the setup icon, the "Table" dialogue box showed English (US) as the Keyboard Layout and "table/cangjie" and "table/Cangjie3" were listed as "Table".

I setup "Chewing" input method and it works well however it is based on Zuyin, which I am not familiar with.

So my questions are:

1. Is the Fcitx Cangjie3 or Cangjie supported by the PowerPc version of Ubuntu mate 16.04 Mate? and
2. If it is, what I need to so to get it work?
3. If it is not, what an I do to have Cangjie input method (for Traditional Chinese) installed?

Since I am a newbie, details instructions will be helpful, and appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I found [`ibus-cangjie 2.4-1`](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/ibus-cangjie). Then I installed with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ibus-cangjie
```

And now it is working perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear that Cangjie works for you with IBus!

Answer (score 2):

Install "Chinese (traditional)" using *Language Support*. That will install some language support, including a couple of additional packages related to fcitx input methods. With those installed it **should** work.

*Edit:*

I've now tried this myself on Ubuntu 16.04 (i386), and it proved to not be sufficient. The package `fcitx-table-cangjie` is installed as part of the language support for "Chinese (traditional)", but after a relogin no Cangjie item showed up in Text Entry.

Then I installed `fcitx-table-cangjie3` manually, and at next login Cangjie3 was selectable. I could successfully generate Chinese characters using Cangjie3.

One important note: The "Keyboard input method system" in *Language Support* must be **fcitx**.

Comment: Thanks. I did try the "Add/Remove Language" in "Language Support" but Cangjie was not listed. Only Chewing was listed for Chinese Taiwan.

Comment: I searched the web and found somebody used "sudo apt-get install fcitx-table-cangjie3" for Ubuntu 15.04. So I copied this method and did get the Cangjie3 installed, but not working. May be the person installed it on Intel PC, not on PowerPC.

Comment: @Wai: Just edited my answer. Possibly you missed that setting in _Language Support_.

Comment: Thanks Gunnar again for you continuous effort to help! My "Keyboard Input Method" was surely set for "facitx" . Can you elaborate a bit on how you manually install "fcitx -table-cangjie3"? Did you mean you use the "sudo apt-get install facitx-table-cangjie3" terminal command?

Comment: @Wai. Yes, that's what I meant. Have no more theories at the moment. You may want to try ibus instead of fcitx.

Answer (score 1):

For whoever is using the Ubuntu22:

Ubuntu22 is default to use ibus input, this is how to install Chinese input method for ibus:

1. make sure you installed the Chinese(traditional) and Chinese(simplified) language via Language Support app.
2. Please note that you don't need to drag up the newly added languge
   to the top
3. open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install ibus-cangjie ibus-table-cangjie
```

If you are using quick input method, add this line of command:

```
sudo apt install ibus-table-quick
```

When it's done, make sure you reboot the system, maybe simply logout will work, but I haven't tried it.
After the reboot, check:

Settings -> Keyboard -> Input Sources -> + -> Chinese(Hong Kong)

now you should see Cangjie input method is available

Answer (score 0):

Go to System setting click on Language Support and press the Install / Remove Languages and there will be a list of languages to choose from pick Chinese Traditional.

Comment: Thanks. I did that but just could not see Cangjie there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Installed Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 on Intel Core, 64bits, i3-7100, with Keyboard Chinese, English (UK) and English (US) and the selected language is English UK, Chinese China, Hong Kong and Taiwan, respectively.

   The "Keyboard input method system" in Language Support must be `fcitx`, ***not*** `iBus`.
2. Run Application "Terminal" and type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install facitx-table-cangjie3
   ```

   Type in password.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install facitx-googlepinyin
   ```

   Type in password.
3. Log out and log into Ubuntu again.
4. Click in the tool bar on the menu ConfigureFcitx. Press *Add*, scroll down the list and select "Cangie3 (Chinese Taiwan)".
   Exit the window.

Done.

Comment: you mean fcitx? (not facitx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to get it to work or don't have a lot of disk space, you can:

1. Download http://chinesecj.com/ime/cj5.php & use cangjie5 offline.
2. Or download cangjieinput.com to use cangjie3 offline.

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu 22.04:**

1. Install Chinese input method for ibus:

`$ sudo apt-get update`

`$ sudo apt-get install ibus-cangjie ibus-table-cangjie ibus-table-quick`

2. It's necessary to install `fcitx` to work the cangjie input:

`$ sudo apt-get install fcitx-table-cangjie3`

3. Reboot to take effect:

`$ reboot`

4. Go to `Settings` > `Keyboard` > `Input Sources`
5. Click `+`
6. Click 'three points' symbol
7. Type "chinese" and click `Other`
8. Finally, there are inputs to select.

That's all